# Using Bayes' with a Multinomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian, multinomial-theorem

This is a problem in a bioinformatics class, and I believe it shouldn't be too difficult probability-wise, but I've a novice in this area. I think I have *about* what I need, but I'm very unsure.
 
I have a table of species' nucleotide frequencies and a DNA sample `ACCGGAGCTC`, and I need to calculate some probabilities regarding how likely it is that my sample belongs to them. 

`Species | %A | %C | %G | %T
--------|----|----|----|----
A       | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25
B       | 20 | 30 | 30 | 20
C       | 30 | 20 | 20 | 30`

In addition, I know the relative abundances of the three species:

`Species | % abundance
A       | 50
B       | 25
C       | 25`

Let $x = [2, 4, 3, 1]$ be the vector of counts of `A`, `C`, `G`, and `T`, respectively, in the sequence given.

`Species | %A | %C | %G | %T
--------|----|----|----|---
sample  | 20 | 40 | 30 | 10`

With $X$ as the random variable representing the vector of *counts* of the bases within a sequence fragment and $Y$ being the random variable representing the species, I need to computer the probability of $x$ given it's species A, given it's species B, given it's species C, and in general. I also need to calculate the probability that it's species B given the sample (which I imagine will be trivial once I have the rest).

**A**
$$P(X = x\ |\ Y = A) = \frac{P(A\ |\ x)\cdot P(x)}{P(A)} = 0.0120163\cdot\frac{12600\cdot0.25^2\cdot0.25^4\cdot0.25^3\cdot0.25^1}{0.50} = 0.0001443914223$$
**B**
$$P(X = x\ |\ Y = B) = \frac{P(B\ |\ x)\cdot P(x)}{P(B)} = 0.0120163\cdot\frac{12600\cdot0.20^2\cdot0.30^4\cdot0.30^3\cdot0.20^1}{0.25} = 0.0002648988528$$
**C**
$$P(X = x\ |\ Y = C) = \frac{P(C\ |\ x)\cdot P(x)}{P(C)} = 0.0120163\cdot\frac{12600\cdot0.30^2\cdot0.20^4\cdot0.20^3\cdot0.30^1}{0.25} = 0.0000523256993$$
**D** -- The average nucleotide for each of A, C, T, G turns out to be 0.25 here, so
$$P(X = x) = \frac{10!}{2!\cdot4!\cdot3!\cdot1!}\cdot0.25^{10} = 0.0120163$$ 
**E**
$$P(Y = B\ |\ X = x) = \frac{P(X = x\ |\ Y = B)\cdot P(Y = B)}{P(X = x)} = \frac{0.0002648988528\cdot 0.25}{0.0120163} = 0.005511239999$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to computer the probability of $x$ given it's species A, given it's species B, given it's species C, and in general. I also need to calculate the probability that it's species B given the sample (which I imagine will be trivial once I have the rest).

You have been told the proportions of the four bases in the species ($0.25\%$ for each in species $\rm A$), so *modelling* the count --of bases in a sample from a species-- as a multinomial distributed random vector, the *conditional probaility* that the *data* (a count of $[2,4,3,1]$) might be generated from a given species $A$ is *approximately*: $$\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}A)=\binom{10}{2,4,3,1} (0.25)^2 (0.25)^4 (0.25)^3 (0.25)^1$$

That is all, and similarly for the others.   Bayes Rule is not used *yet*.

*Tip: Don't worry about evaluating the multinomial coefficients until the final answer.*

---

> D -- The average nucleotide for each of A, C, T, G turns out to be 0.25 here, so

No, you cannot do that.   All bases in the sample are selected from the *same* species.   The data is only (approximately) multinomially distributed for a given species.

Use the Law of Total Probability. $$\mathsf P(X{=}x)=\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}A)\mathsf P(Y{=}A)+\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}B)\mathsf P(Y{=}B)+\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}C)\mathsf P(Y{=}C)$$

---

**Now** use Bayes' Rule: $$\mathsf P(Y{=}B\mid X{=}x)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}B)\mathsf P(Y{=}B)}{\mathsf P(X{=}x)}$$

Comment: Exactly as you said, I was using Bayes' too early

Comment: $$P(X = x\ |\ Y = A) = \frac{10!}{2!\cdot4!\cdot3!\cdot1!} \left(0.25^2\cdot0.25^4\cdot0.25^3\cdot0.25^1\right) = 0.012016$$   
$$P(X = x\ |\ Y = B) = \frac{10!}{2!\cdot4!\cdot3!\cdot1!} \left(0.20^2\cdot0.30^4\cdot0.30^3\cdot0.20^1\right) = 0.02205$$  
$$P(X = x\ |\ Y = C) = \frac{10!}{2!\cdot4!\cdot3!\cdot1!} \left(0.30^2\cdot0.20^4\cdot0.20^3\cdot0.30^1\right) = 0.004355$$  
$$P(X = x) = P(x\ |\ A)\cdot P(A) + P(x\ |\ B)\cdot P(B) + P( x\ |\ C)\cdot P(C) = 0.01261$$ 
$$P(Y = B\ |\ X = x) = \frac{P(X = x\ |\ Y = B)\cdot P(Y = B)}{P(X = x)} = \frac{0.02204\cdot 0.25}{0.012608} = 0.4371$$`